# PHP include path (Linux)

Tags: php

Say a php file has `include_once("$CONF/blah.inc")` in it. Where is this $CONF and the default location?

Comment: $CONF is not a variable which is available by default. It must be located somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$CONF is a configuration variable set in an already sourced file. The search path is relative to at least one element from the include_path variable.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Search it..

```
grep -R CONF *
```

Answer (score 1):

`$CONF` looks like a normal PHP variable to me. Try poking around the the files you include earlier.